# Group sums of an attribute by the values of another array attribute

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection "tagsCount" that looks like that:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("59e3a46a48507851d411ad78"),
    "tags" : [ "Marketing" ],
    "cpt" : 14354 
},
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("59e3a46a48507851d411ad79"), 
    "tags" : [ 
        "chatbot", 
        "Content marketing", 
        "Intelligence artificielle",
        "Marketing digital",
        "Personnalisation"
    ], 
    "cpt" : 9037 
}
```

Of course there are many more lines.

I want to get the sum of "cpt" grouped by the values of "tags".

I have come up with that:

```
db.tagsCount.aggregate([
    { "$project": { "tags":1 }}, 
    { "$unwind": "$tags"},
    { "$group": { 
        "_id" : "$tags", 
        cpt : "$cpt" ,
        "count": { "$sum": "$cpt" }
    }}
])
```

But that doesn't do the trick, I have the list of all different tags and the count have a value a 0.

Is it possible to do what I want?

Comment: Your `$group` stage is not valid. Also consider to show us the expected result.

Comment: Try `{ "$group": { 
        "_id": "$tags", 
        "count": { "$sum": "$cpt" }
    }}`

Comment: @sstyvane I edited the `$group` stage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your aggregation pipeline starts with **$project** which selects only tags to the next stages and that's why you're executing **$group** on documents without cpt. Here's my working example:

```
db.tagsCount.aggregate([
   { "$unwind": "$tags"},
   { "$group": { 
       "_id": "$tags",
       "count": { "$sum": "$cpt" }
   }},
   { "$project": { "tag": "$_id", "_id": 0, "count": 1 }}
```

])

Comment: Thank you. I'm going to try this out. I'm really new at mongodb and I have yet to really understand `$project` so that makes sense I messed up on that.